# Exempt a child element from auto layout in CSS grid without using position: fixed?

Tags: css, css-grid

Is there a way to "exempt" a child element of a grid container from participating in the grid layout *other than using `position:fixed` or `display:contents;`* on the child?

For instance, given something simple like:

```css
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}
```

```html
<div>Element One</div>
<div>Element Two</div>
<div>Element Three</div>
<div>Element Four</div>
<custom-web-component id="exemptedElement">Exempted Element</custom-web-component>
```

Is it possible to somehow via CSS or otherwise tell that last element not to participate in the grid layout?

I know that I could set `position: fixed;` on that element, and it would do so, but that has downstream implications within that component (e.g. a descendant with `position: absolute;` would be locked to the viewport, rather than the document as intended).

I know that I could also set `display: contents` on that element, and it would not participate, deferring the layout to its children... but that again has downstream implications meaning the children of this main component all need to be careful about the above fixed/absolute positioning issue.

**Note: I do not have control over the fact that the custom-web-component is sometimes being added to a grid container. So I'm trying to find some way to "Break out" of it when that does happen.**

Comment: exempted in any way? you want it to be full width?

Comment: Basically I want it to not participate in the grid layout at all - not take up a "slot" in the auto layout, not cause any reflows, etc. The component doesn't actually render anything directly (its descendants do, but they're all fixed/absolute) and so don't impact the grid layout. But the web component itself - even though it renders nothing - ends up messing up the grid layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot use absolute/fixed or `display: contents` then you can *approximate* the behavior by making the element height: 0, spanning all the columns and have a big order to be paced at the end.

I insist on the fact that it's an approximation as I don't think it's possible with all your constraints.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

custom-web-component {
  grid-column: 1/-1; /* span all the possible columns */
  height: 0;
  order: 99;
  
  /* to illustre */
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>Element One</div>
<div>Element Two</div>
<custom-web-component id="exemptedElement">Exempted Element</custom-web-component>
<div>Element Three</div>
<div>Element Four</div>
<div>Element five</div>
```

Comment: "I don't think it's possible with all your constraints"

That's certainly an acceptable answer too! Thanks for the tip here, I'm pondering if I can do this dynamically...

Comment: This ended up working well enough for me. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score -1):

can you afford to break out your exempted component from the css grid and then wrap the grid and the exempted component together via relative and absolute positions?

```css
.grid-ele-wrapper {
   position: relative;

   border: red 1px solid;
}

.grid-ele {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

#exemptedElement {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
  <div class="grid-ele-wrapper">
  <div class="grid-ele">
    <div>Element One</div>
    <div>Element Two</div>
    <div>Element Three</div>
    <div>Element Four</div>
  </div>
  <custom-web-component id="exemptedElement">Exempted Element</custom-web-component>
</div>
```

*red box is a visual aid to show the exempted element is outside the wrapper

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for me. I don't have control over the way the page is laid out - just the styling of the custom component.

Comment: ah ya, that sounds difficult. not totally sure how much control you have in that situation but maybe set `grid-row: 1000; grid-column: 1000` or some other super large number

Answer (score -1):

Just wrap the grid elements in a container and use that.

I added some borders just to show where the actual children lie

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  border: 1px solid #4444ff;
}

.grid-container>* {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border: solid 1px #44ff44;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>Element One</div>
  <div>Element Two</div>
  <div>Element Three</div>
  <div>Element Four</div>
</div>
<custom-web-component id="exemptedElement">Exempted Element</custom-web-component>
```

This uses some JavaScript - which may be out of scope but leverages the fact that CSS `display:grid;` applies only to direct descendants and moves the target element out of the grid.
Lots of comments that should be deleted in any production code.

Note: only this CSS is needed; the rest is just for illustration:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
}
```

```js
// function to get all the siblings
const getSiblings = elm => elm && elm.parentNode && [...elm.parentNode.children].filter(node => node != elm);

// create a new container div with a class for the "grid"
let gridContainer = document.createElement('div');
gridContainer.className = "grid-container";

// CSS grid applies only to direct children so let's leverage that

let elem = document.getElementById("exemptedElement");
let elementParent = elem.parentNode;
// get all the element siblings; assumes no text
// get all siblings NOT the element from the parent
let siblings = getSiblings(elem);

siblings.forEach(el => gridContainer.appendChild(el));
// put the grid container back in the parent node: 
// last
//elementParent.appendChild(gridContainer);
// OR prepend as first
elementParent.prepend(gridContainer);
```

```css
body {
  border: 2px solid #444433;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid #ff4444ff;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.grid-container>* {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border: solid 1px #44ff44;
}

#exemptedElement {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border: solid 1px #4444ff;
}
```

```html
<div>Element One</div>
<div>Element Two</div>
<div>Element Three</div>
<div>Element Four</div>
<custom-web-component id="exemptedElement">Exempted Element</custom-web-component>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for me. I don't have control over the way the page is laid out - just the styling of the custom component.

Comment: I added a second example that MAY work depending on if you can use JavaScript also. NOTE: you can add a JavaScript to detect if the element exist before doing the wrap if desired - this second example assumes it does but that check is pretty easy.